# Undefined variable: returnValue

Tags: php

```
<?php

namespace StripeIntegration\Payments\Plugin\Sales\Model\Service;

class OrderService
{
    public function __construct(
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Rollback $rollback,
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\GenericFactory $helperFactory
    ) {
        $this->rollback = $rollback;
        $this->helperFactory = $helperFactory;
    }

    public function aroundPlace($subject, \Closure $proceed, $order)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->rollback->reset();
            $returnValue = $proceed($order);
            $this->rollback->reset();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            $helper = $this->helperFactory->create();
            \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Logger::log($e->getMessage());
            if ($order->getId())
            {
                // The order has already been saved, so we don't want to run the rollback. The exception likely occurred in an order_save_after observer.
                $this->rollback->reset();
                $helper->dieWithError($e->getMessage(), $e);
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
                if (!$this->isAuthenticationRequiredMessage($msg))
                    $this->rollback->run($e);
                else
                    $this->rollback->reset(); // In case some customization is trying to place multiple split-orders

                $helper->dieWithError($e->getMessage(), $e);
            }
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }

}
```

Any thoughts how to solve this error ?
I am using magento version 2.4
we the call run through this file the error appears
It seems like the variable is not getting any data in code.
I need some fix to prevent this error

Comment: `$returnValue` is crated in a `try - catch` block, but returned after. The only explanation is that the only line before it (`$this->rollback->reset();`) threw an exception so the execution of the `try` block stopped and the variable was never created.

Comment: `$returnValue` is defined in the try block. But if the first instruction fails, `$returnValue` is never set. So you should declare it first after function header like `$returnValue = null`;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to access the variable `returnValue` which is not defined. Your code throws an exception in the closure (or it could be in the `reset()` function), so `returnValue` is never defined.

What's happening:

1. Enters try block
2. Calls the function reset(). Lets assume this doesn't throw the exception
3. Calls the closure. This throws an exception. So your variable is not successfully defined.
4. Goes to the catch block
5. Goes to return. At this point, the variable `returnValue` is never defined

A possible fix it to declare the variable with some value on top like shown below

```php
namespace StripeIntegration\Payments\Plugin\Sales\Model\Service;

class OrderService
{
    public function __construct(
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Rollback $rollback,
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\GenericFactory $helperFactory
    ) {
        $this->rollback = $rollback;
        $this->helperFactory = $helperFactory;
    }

    public function aroundPlace($subject, \Closure $proceed, $order)
    {
        $returnValue = null; // Or have it equal to some meaningful value
        try
        {
            $this->rollback->reset();
            $returnValue = $proceed($order);
            $this->rollback->reset();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }

}
```